# Language for allowing users to write simple mathematical functions with no state change?

Tags: python, django, functional-programming, dsl

I am writing a small simulation where users can trade assets and I want them to be able to trade options too. Options are basically mathematical functions

```
f(Asset_price : [float]) -> float
```

that should not need to make any state change. It would be optimal if the users could supply these functions themselves. The app is written in python/django but of course I cannot just let them upload python code and execute that. Is there some simple way to still let the users handcode these functions?

My idea would be some very simplistic language that I can easily call from python that only allows the users to do some basic mathematical operations in the function `f` and not allowing any state change to the environment. Is there something like that out there?

I am also open for different suggestions on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Lua is an embeddable programming language that allows you to apply as much or as little security around user input as you want.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I allow the users to upload Lua code and execute that? Can I somehow make sure that the code has no side effects and only calculates the option value?

Comment: Normally, you would run a Lua sandbox inside of server code running Java or C++ or something. You might be able to provide a sandbox from Python that will ensure that the code has no side effects.

Comment: It should be very easy to implement such a language as an interpreter in Python, if you're ok with an unavoidably abysmal performance of such a solution. If you can use PyPy, you can get an optimising compiler for your language nearly for free. Otherwise, LLVM could have been a viable choice for a backend.